# Create / delete matrix formula with Macros

Tags: excel, vba, matrix

I´m using this formula:

```
=SI.ERROR(INDICE(TablaC;K.ESIMO.MENOR(SI($C$2=Vertical;FILA()-7);FILA()-7);6);"")
```

in a matrix to get data from a table. This way, I can take different lines of data if `X` value in the table is equal to `Y`.
I'm using this in 4 columns getting info from different columns.

Works fine once, problem is when I want to use in the same cell, macros with other similar formulas but just updating the equal to `Y` argument. I can't find a way without errors to, in the same cell... delete Matrix formula and insert new one.

Do you know if is possible?

Using macros, create a matrix formula in the same cell, and click on different buttons swapping one formula to another

Comment: a) The majority of users here won't understand a local formula input; please communicate the VBA (i.e. English) version of the formula by **editing** your question - just read the cell range's  `.FormulaArray` property. b) What exactly do you mean by *"This way, I can take different lines of data if X value in the table is equal to Y"*? c) Will be helpful to explain further variables or range/table names as well as d) the purpose of your macro.

Comment: Hola Felix, podrias editar tu pregunta y/o explicarla mejor en ingles (no se entiende) o agregar una sección en español (asumo que hablas español por la formula posteada, disculpa si no es así) , donde expliques mejor lo que deseas.